# Recommend nodes based on current node field value in view block

Tags: views, nodes

I have made a view block to show on each node for recommending other node of similar interest type.

Every node have a field called **Main Category**, which is taxonomy.

I want to show those node title which has similar category where view block is attached(I mean at node page).

Note - I have attached view block into node by [EVA](https://drupal.org/project/eva) field.

Comment: "the unique ID of the entity the view is attached to -- as well as any tokens generated from that entity -- can be passed in as arguments to the view." - so, have you tried to set up arguments? What problem with it do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a module for that: [Similar by Terms](https://drupal.org/project/similarterms)

However, it's possible with views as well: [Creating list of similar nodes in Drupal 7/Views 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454507/creating-list-of-similar-nodes-in-drupal-7-views-3)

Alternatively, you can use my configuration:

**An example of view block with related nodes based on 'tags'.**

1. Create a block (take a look at screenshots below)
2. Add a relationship: *Taxonomy term: Content using: Tags*
3. Add contextual filter: *(field_tags) Content: Nid*
   **When the filter value is NOT available**
   Provide default value -> Content ID from URL
   **MORE**
   check: Exclude
   *this contextual filter will remove current node from the view*
4. Add contextual filter: *Taxonomy term: Term ID*
   **When the filter value is NOT available**
   Provide default value -> Taxonomy term ID from URL
   check: Load default filter from term page 
   check: Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks
   choose the vocabulary (tags in this case)
   Multiple-value handling -> Filter to items that share any term
   **When the filter value IS available or a default is provided**
   Specify validation criteria  -> Basic validation
   **MORE**
   check:  Allow multiple values
5. Define the fields (only titles in this case)
6. Make the view display only distinct items
   **Other -> Query settings:**
   check: Distinct
   check: Pure distinct

---

**Screenshots:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]