# Views filter by contextual filter

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have an interesting question regarding Views, Taxonomy and Contextual Filters AND Views->Filters

I have a content type Basic Page with additional field -> *industry category* (term reference, taxonomy).

There are multiple Basic Pages on the website but only 5 with industry category field filled in.

I have second content type Industry Page (Page Title, Body with additional field -> *industry categor*y (term reference, taxonomy), pointing towards the same vocabulary.

I have a view should display nodes of type industry page depending on the page you are in (The “*basic page*” with the additional *field-> industry category*.)

I need to do something with contextual filter to display all nodes of type “industry page” **where** the basic page->field industry category = “industry page”->industry category.

Can you help me with it, since I am a bit stuck.

Regards

Oleg

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for creating a block of similar node by term with one more filter "another content type". There is a module to do this exactly but it doesn't have the content type filter in it. I will still recommend you to have a look at it - [Similarterms](https://drupal.org/project/similarterms).

You can achieving the same with view. Please look into the answer given at these links, it has been explained in details --

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454507/creating-list-of-similar-nodes-in-drupal-7-views-3

[Recommend nodes based on current node field value in view block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79746/recommend-nodes-based-on-current-node-field-value-in-view-block)